# Запятая в предложении: "А как этот фильм продвигали и рекламировали(,) я прекрасно помню"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите, запятая в предложении поставлена правильно?

**А как этот фильм продвигали и рекламировали, я прекрасно помню.**

Comment: Пробелы тоже характеризуют правильность в пунктуации. Нетакли,ПётрГринёв?

Answer (score 3):

Абсолютно верно: придаточное изъяснительное стоит впереди, А относится именно к нему. Но возможно и тире:

*"А как этот фильм продвигали и рекламировали  -  я прекрасно помню".*

Я бы тире поставила.